# Tables with float attributes refuse to be in div, even though the table tags are literally inside of the div tags

Tags: html, css

I made two tables side by side in one div that's colored grey. However, the tables are outside of the div even though they're literally within the div tags. This is because of the float attribute. Without it, it works fine

```css
#table1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

#table2 {
  position: relative;
  right: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="table1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <header>
          <h2>TABLE 1</h2>
        </header>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="table2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <header>
          <h2>TABLE 2</h2>
        </header>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Test it, the tables refuse to go inside the div.

Comment: You're trying to wrap floated elements; which makes this question a duplicate (though in fairness it's difficult to know what the problem is while you're searching for a solution to a problem you haven't encountered).

Comment: Once an element is `float`ed, its parent elements no longer flow around it. Since everything inside your `<div>` has `float` set, there is no content left to give it any height.

Answer (score 1):

Parent elements are not to expand to contain floated elements. So your parent div collapses as it properly should.

To get the div to do what you want, add `overflow:auto;` or `overflow:hidden;` to its CSS.

Comment: THANK YOU. But if that;s the case, how would you make two tables side by side, one on each side, that doesnt use float?

Comment: Nothing changes to prevent you from doing that. Your question was about the containing div.

Comment: [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [`display: grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) (stupidly simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h01j9qxL/)).

Comment: @JohnDoe Use CSS Flexbox

Comment: Learn Flexbox the easy way: https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: @Rob Or, give the div a width/height

Comment: @AshleyBrown He doesn't need to learn flexbox or grid in order to accomplish what he wants.

Comment: He asked **how** could he do X, and flexbox **is** a way it *could* be done

Comment: @AshleyBrown Yes, but it's far far more complex than just putting `overflow` in and be done with it.

Comment: @Rob `overflow` doesn't answer the question of how to have two tables positioned either side of each other without the use of `float`

Comment: @AshleyBrown Read the title again. That is not what the question is. The question is about the tables staying inside the div.

Comment: @Rob Let me quote their question for you " But if that;s the case, how would you make two tables side by side, one on each side, that doesnt use float?"

Comment: @AshleyBrown READ THE QUESTION NOT A COMMENT HERE ABOUT SOMETHING ELSE UNRELATED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Is what I quoted not a question? Are the tables in question not mentioned in the initial question? Don't be so hostile with your approach, it's not a good look.